# Table width can't be set below 385 pixels and responsiveness issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Bootstrap and have a part in my code that is:

```
<table class="table">...</table>
```

In my header, I have the tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">` This actually works fine(I can see the whole table on my website) but when I add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width initial-scale=1">` like is suggested on many websites, my table doesn't fit the 320 px width viewport that I have been using to test and I have to scroll to see the whole table.

Further investigation and playing around with the css for .table shows that I can't manually set width below 385 px. I have tried searching "bootstrap table 385 px" but it doesn't seem like there is anything special about this number so I am wondering why the table can't be smaller. Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can make the table smaller or make it scale correctly to initial-scale=1?

Edit #1:

```
<table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Col1</th>
      <th>Col2</th>
      <th>Col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="..."> ...
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="..."> ...
      </td>
      <td width=70%>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="...">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="...">...</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="... in ...">
      <td class="claimedby-{{...}}">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="..." ng-click="...">&nbsp;{{...}}
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="..." ng-click="..."> ...
      </td>
      <td>
        <div for="...">
          <div class="...">{{...}}</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="...">...</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Sorry for the "..." in certain places. I'm not sure if we're allowed to post exact code publicly. Hopefully this is enough to see what's going wrong though.

Comment: Can we get some code? There are 2 common problems accotiated with 320px and bootstrap.

Comment: How many columns are you using?

Comment: I am using 4 columns. Will provide table code in edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here, this should do it for you

```
    <table class="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="col-md-4 col-xs-2">Col1</th>
      <th class="col-md-4 col-xs-2">Col2</th>
      <th class="col-md-4 col-xs-8">Col3</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="..."> ...
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="..."> ...
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="form-control" ng-model="...">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="...">...</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="... in ...">
      <td class="claimedby-{{...}}">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="..." ng-click="...">&nbsp;{{...}}
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="..." ng-click="..."> ...
      </td>
      <td>
        <div for="...">
          <div class="...">{{...}}</div>
        </div>
      </td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-danger" ng-click="...">...</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for that, but can you explain what exactly col-md-4 col-xs-2 is doing? I know Bootstrap works with a (12?) column gridding system, but why are there both col-md-4 and col-xs-2?

Comment: the md and xs has to to with the breakpoints, they are saying at a curtain width do something for instance the md has its break point for anything below or equal to 768px wide. the number at the end like 2 or 4 has to do with the width, if you have a new row, it is 100% wide or 12, so if you have a 2 its saying to make that column 2 out of a max of 12 wide, you can have less than or equal to 12 on any row but you cannot be bigger than the 12. here is a link to w3 fools that explains all this better. http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Comment: I tried this and have included a screen shot [here](http://postimg.org/image/xqw2smqrz/). It didn't really change anything, and as you can see the shaded area, which has the dimension of the page, is still at 385 pixels.. Any ideas?

Comment: That screen shot is not opening?

Comment: for your smallest media query add this `.form-control{width: 33%;}`

Comment: should I add this to my styles.css? I've never used media query before but I can read up on it- is it the @media-query thing?